# DbContext class, can't find

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dbcontext

please check this example http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/adding-a-model and do tell me that where the "DbContext" class is from which MovieDbContext class has been copied. I can't find.
this one:

```
 public class MovieDBContext : DbContext 
 {
   public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; } 
 }
```

and do tell me that what does DbSet means ? what it do ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext(v=vs.113).aspx

Answer (score 3):

These are Entity Framework classes. You would need to add the Entity Framework DLLs as a reference in your project. They are available through Nuget Package Manager, within Visual Studio.

The link that you provided says this:

> **You’ll use** a .NET Framework data-access technology known as the **Entity**
>    **Framework** to define and work with these model classes. The Entity
>   Framework (often referred to as EF) supports a development paradigm
>   called Code First. Code First allows you to create model objects by
>   writing simple classes. (These are also known as POCO classes, from
>   "plain-old CLR objects.") You can then have the database created on
>   the fly from your classes, which enables a very clean and rapid
>   development workflow.

Comment: I´m struggling with a similiar project, where the compiler throws an error telling it cannot find DbContext and DbSet classes, but the source code has the using System.Data.Entity which is suposed to contain both classes.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not find DbContext, this means that EntityFramework is not in the project References. To easily install EntityFramework, launch the Nuget Packages Manager console and type `Install-Package EntityFramework`.
This command will automatically install the latest version of the package.
Go into your class that should inherit from DbContext, and add at the very top, the `using System.Data.Entity;` directive. It worked for me.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/350567) by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 1):

[DBSet](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/dbsetclass.aspx) class represents an entity set that is use for create, read, update, and delete operations. A generic version of DBSet (DbSet) can be used when the type of entity is not known at build time.